# Popping fragments out and keeping them single instances

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to solve the back button between my fragments in the activity.
for that, I have done:

```
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, new HomeFragmentFeed());
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
```

And to handle the backs:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

        if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1)        
            fm.popBackStack();      
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Problem is that if I navigate between the fragments without popping them out, each can be multiple times in the stack.
How can  I solve the issue in which each fragment should be only ONCE in the stack.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible so What i suggest you do is clear the backstack every time you make a fragment transaction. In this way only last fragment will be in the backstack

```
popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to preserve the stack itself, so back button will always return me to the previous fragment

Comment: @Himberjack i think you should use your own data structure for this type of behaviour. I think using a hashmap which has fragments would be a good approach. In this way you can check whether or not the instance of that fragment is in the hashmap and if it is available then you could use it instead of creating a new fragment  :)